# how can I be sure about the correctness of a .d.ts file I'm writing? (is there is way VScode warns me? like its intellisense)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

for example, in the below file structure if I change the type of `thing` to `string` (defined type in `my-module.d.ts` file) I won't see any warning in either of those three files by VScode.

```
src/
  my-module.js
  my-module.d.ts
  index.ts
```

my-module.js:

```js
const thing = 42;
module.exports = { thing };
```

my-module.d.ts:

```js
export declare const thing: number;
```

index.ts:

```js
import { thing } from "./my-module";
console.log(thing); // 42
type TypeOfThing = typeof thing; // number
```

Comment: That's kinda the point... `d.ts` declares what the type of the file should be to the enduser. If you really need to do this, why not write the project in TypeScript? If this is for typing an existing library that is in JavaScript (and you can't really just "rewrite" it), then I don't think it's possible.

Comment: oh. you solved a mystery for me.